# MS Access Report not showing Image from a Linked Table

Tags: ms-access, ole-object

I have a Linked Table from a SQL Server that has Images in one column. Trying to print the Image on Report but all I get is a blank picture box. When I open the Query and look at the data, that column only shows "OLE object". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks
Bennie

Tried adding Image column to Report and Form and it just shows blank.